# Two nested update panels on same aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have two nested UpdatePanel controls on apsx page. The outer one is for the whole page and displays "Loading Page..." img, while the purpose of inner one is to load a grid on dropdownlist selectedIndexChanged

I get this error while both have different names:
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id 'cphMainContent_Updprog3' can't be added to the application.

Please guide. Here is the code structure:

```
     <asp:content id="HeaderContent" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="head">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function showProgress() {
                var updateProgress = $get("<%=Updprog3.ClientID %>");
                updateProgress.style.display = "block";
            }

        </script>
    </asp:content>

    <asp:content id="BodyContent" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="cphMainContent">
        <div style="padding-left:36px; padding-top:10px;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
    <table align="left">

           <tr>
                <td style="border: none; width:120px">
                    Call Category Group:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" 
                        onChange="javascript:showProgress()"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="400px">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--- Select Group ---</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Group 1"> Group 1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Group 2">Group 2</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>

      <!--2nd update panel-->
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCallCategoryGroup" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
        </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlgvSecondLevelLoading" CssClass="modalwindow">
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="Updprog3" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdPnl">
        <ProgressTemplate>
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" width="35%">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgSubCallCategory_Wait3" runat="server" ImageUrl="ProjectImages/Wait_Small.gif" />
                            </td>
                            <td width="2%">
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="73%">
                                Loading data . . .
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLoading" CssClass="modalwindow">
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="container2">
                    <div class="content">
                        <br />
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" width="35%">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgSubCallCategory_Wait2" runat="server" ImageUrl="ProjectImages/30-1.gif" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="2%">
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" width="73%">
                                    Loading Page . . .
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </asp:Panel>
         </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel> 
    </div>
</asp:content>
```

Comment: Where is your script manager?

Comment: It is in the master page. UpdatePanel1 has been there for a while. I am now adding UpdPnl now since the grid takes a long time to load and facing issues

Comment: Please show the markup for the master page or at least the script manager.

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="WebApp" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="36000">
        </asp:ScriptManager>  ScriptManager is not the issue since the application has been working with one UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="WebApp" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="36000" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Actually, we are using a master page that is used globally by all applications and I cannot change it. What does ScriptMode="Release" do by the way? does it set application to Release mode instead of debug?

Comment: ScriptMode controls which versions of the client scripts are sent to the browser. If you're sharing the master page with multiple applications (what?) you will want to verify this change doesn't impact other pages, but unless you have a specific reason you need to use .debug.js files instead of the standard .js versions it should be fine.